# Reduce number of mysql count query for different time interval

Tags: php, mysql

I am using below query:

```
$select_jan1 = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31'";
$select_feb1 = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28'";
$select_mar1 = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE timeStamp BETWEEN '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-31'";
```

Is there way to put this 3 query in one ?

Thank You

Comment: You want individual results form each query or you need just a single(i.e. combined) result from all the query. Please specify your question a bit more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the values in three columns, using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(timeStamp BETWEEN '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-31') as cnt_201501,
       SUM(timeStamp BETWEEN '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28') as cnt_201502,
       SUM(timeStamp BETWEEN '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-31') as cnt_201503       
FROM users;
```

Do note that this logic ignores that values on the last day of each month.  Better logic is:

```
SELECT SUM(timeStamp >= '2015-01-01' and timestamp < '2015-02-01') as cnt_201501,
       SUM(timeStamp >= '2015-02-01' and timestamp < '2015-03-01') as cnt_201502,
       SUM(timeStamp >= '2015-03-01' and timestamp < '2015-04-01') as cnt_201503       
FROM users
WHERE timeStamp >= '2015-01-01' and timeStamp < '2015-04-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

With whole months, I do so:

```
SELECT
count(*)
FROM
(SELECT
year(timestamp) AS year_, month(timestamp) AS month_
FROM
users) s
WHERE
s.year_ = 2015 AND s.month_ >=4
```